# How can I launch PowerToys Run with just the Windows key?

Tags: powertoys

I've installed [Microsoft PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) and I want to configure PowerToys Run so that it launches when I press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key on the keyboard.

The settings allow me to change the keyboard shortcut to something like <kbd>Windows</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, but changing it to just <kbd>Windows</kbd> does not seem to be permitted.

I already am used to pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> when I want to type the name of an application that I want to launch, and I want to use PowerToys Run instead of the default Windows behaviour because it is offline and faster. I would like to use the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key so that I don't have to retrain my muscle memory.

Comment: Remapping the Windows key is possible, but is still a very bad idea. I recommend finding another key.

Comment: @harrymc Why is it a bad idea? How can it be done?

Comment: Just for the challenge, I did the mapping in my answer, without disabling all the numerous shortcuts in which this key takes part.

Answer (score 2):

The idea in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1728025/105457) was great, however, attempting to have it run `PowerToys.exe` didn't work. I've used that idea to create the following script that is working well.

Assuming that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is currently mapped to your PowerToys Run, using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/):

```
$LWin::
KeyWait, LWin, T0.2
If !ErrorLevel              ; if you hold the LWin key for less than 200 miliseconds...
    send {Alt Down}{Space Down}{Alt Up}{Alt Up}
Else                        ; but if it is held for more than that...
    Send, {LWin Down}       ; ...hold LWin down
KeyWait, LWin               ; and, in both cases, wait for it to be released
Send, {LWin Up}
Return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a file with an `.ahk` extension and double-click on it.  Then short-press press the  (Windows) key to see the result.

Of course, if you have PowerToys Run mapped to some other key chord, then make the appropriate adjustments in the script above to have it simulate pressing those keys.

Comment: Just to be clear, the only difference with the other answer is this line, right? `send {Alt Down}{Space Down}{Alt Up}{Alt Up}`

Comment: @Flimm That is correct.  Ali identified an issue with the other answer, so I recommended the creation of a new answer.  Edits shouldn't be made by other users that fundamentally change the answer, and this was a significant enough change IMHO that it deserved a new answer, rather than a comment.  Subsequently, harrymc also updated the original answer with the same change (without attribution, unfortunately), but I don't know which one came first at this point, since they were both "1 hour ago".

Answer (score 1):

It's actually possible to remap a tap on the left Windows key to
doing something, while distinguishing it from the long press
that is required when using this key as part of a shortcut
such as <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

You may use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will do this. Replace if necessary the path
to the powertoys executable (code modified as influenced by
comment and answer of user Ali):

```
$LWin::
KeyWait, LWin, T0.2
If !ErrorLevel              ; if you hold the LWin key for less than 200 miliseconds...
    send {Alt Down}{Space Down}{Space Up}{Alt Up}   ; ...run powertoys launcher
Else                        ; but if it is held for more than that...
    Send, {LWin Down}       ; ...hold LWin down
KeyWait, LWin               ; and, in both cases, wait for it to be released
Send, {LWin Up}
Return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Interesting! This does seem to activate when pressing the Windows key. Unfortunately, it launches the PowerToys Settings window, rather than the PowerToys Run launcher. And I'm guessing that launching a new process is not the most efficient. Is it possible to make it instead simulate pressing the real keyboard shortcut that would trigger PowerToys Run?

Comment: Replace in the script `C:\Program Files\PowerToys\PowerToys.exe` by the right path to the PowerToys Run launcher. I don't have it installed, so can't tell which executable is it. If unsure, right-click the launcher in the Start menu and select Properties.

Comment: I have modified you script in:
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/5571#issuecomment-1236652943

Comment: @Ali Agree that sending the PowerToys Run shortcut keys in response does improve the situation.  Would recommend posting your modifications as a separate answer (with link and credit to harrymc's answer for the original idea).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I have created a new answer